# Trying to access data in JSON data structure read from file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have the following Python code to read a JSON file:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
with open('traveladvisory.json') as json_data:
    print 'json data ',json_data
    d = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()
```

Below is a piece of the 'traveladvisory.json' file opened with this code. The variable 'd' does print out all the JSON data. But I can't seem to get the syntax correct to read all of the 'country-eng' and 'advisory-text' fields and their data and print it out. Can someone assist? Here's a piece of the json data (sorry, can't get it pretty printed):

```json
{
   "metadata":{
      "generated":{
         "timestamp":1475854624,
         "date":"2016-10-07 11:37:04"
      }
   },
   "data":{
      "AF":{
         "country-id":1000,
         "country-iso":"AF",
         "country-eng":"Afghanistan",
         "country-fra":"Afghanistan",
         "advisory-state":3,
         "date-published":{
            "timestamp":1473866215,
            "date":"2016-09-14 11:16:55",
            "asp":"2016-09-14T11:16:55.000000-04:00"
         },
         "has-advisory-warning":1,
         "has-regional-advisory":0,
         "has-content":1,
         "recent-updates-type":"Editorial change",
         "eng":{
            "name":"Afghanistan",
            "url-slug":"afghanistan",
            "friendly-date":"September 14, 2016 11:16 EDT",
            "advisory-text":"Avoid all travel",
            "recent-updates":"The Health tab was updated - travel health notices (Public Health Agency of Canada)."
         },
         "fra":{
            "name":"Afghanistan",
            "url-slug":"afghanistan",
            "friendly-date":"14 septembre 2016 11:16 HAE",
            "advisory-text":"\u00c9viter tout voyage",
            "recent-updates":"L'onglet Sant\u00e9 a \u00e9t\u00e9 mis \u00e0 jour - conseils de sant\u00e9 aux voyageurs (Agence de la sant\u00e9 publique du Canada)."
         }
      },
      "AL":{
         "country-id":4000,
         "country-iso":"AL",
         "country-eng":"Albania",
         "country-fra":"Albanie",
         "advisory-state":0,
         "date-published":{
            "timestamp":1473350931,
            "date":"2016-09-08 12:08:51",
            "asp":"2016-09-08T12:08:51.8301256-04:00"
         },
         "has-advisory-warning":0,
         "has-regional-advisory":1,
         "has-content":1,
         "recent-updates-type":"Editorial change",
         "eng":{
            "name":"Albania",
            "url-slug":"albania",
            "friendly-date":"September 8, 2016 12:08 EDT",
            "advisory-text":"Exercise normal security precautions (with regional advisories)",
            "recent-updates":"An editorial change was made."
         },
         "fra":{
            "name":"Albanie",
            "url-slug":"albanie",
            "friendly-date":"8 septembre 2016 12:08 HAE",
            "advisory-text":"Prendre des mesures de s\u00e9curit\u00e9 normales (avec avertissements r\u00e9gionaux)",
            "recent-updates":"Un changement mineur a \u00e9t\u00e9 apport\u00e9 au contenu."
         }
      },
      "DZ":{
         "country-id":5000,
         "country-iso":"DZ",
         "country-eng":"Algeria",
         "country-fra":"Alg\u00e9rie",
         "advisory-state":1,
         "date-published":{
            "timestamp":1475593497,
            "date":"2016-10-04 11:04:57",
            "asp":"2016-10-04T11:04:57.7727548-04:00"
         },
         "has-advisory-warning":0,
         "has-regional-advisory":1,
         "has-content":1,
         "recent-updates-type":"Full TAA review",
         "eng":{
            "name":"Algeria",
            "url-slug":"algeria",
            "friendly-date":"October 4, 2016 11:04 EDT",
            "advisory-text":"Exercise a high degree of caution (with regional advisories)",
            "recent-updates":"This travel advice was thoroughly reviewed and updated."
         },
         "fra":{
            "name":"Alg\u00e9rie",
            "url-slug":"algerie",
            "friendly-date":"4 octobre 2016 11:04 HAE",
            "advisory-text":"Faire preuve d\u2019une grande prudence (avec avertissements r\u00e9gionaux)",
            "recent-updates":"Les pr\u00e9sents Conseils aux voyageurs ont \u00e9t\u00e9 mis \u00e0 jour \u00e0 la suite d\u2019un examen minutieux."
         }
      },

   }
}
```

Comment: You should get rid of the comma on the 4th to last time. It could cause a json decode error

Comment: no need to close the file, the context handler `with` will do that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming d contains the json Data

```
for country in d["data"]:
    print "Country :",country

    #country.get() gets the value of the key . the second argument is 
    #the value returned in case the key is not present

    print "country-eng : ",country.get("country-eng",0)
    print "advisory-text(eng) :",country["eng"].get("advisory-text",0)
    print "advisory-text(fra) :",country["fra"].get("advisory-text",0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
for item in d['data']:
    print d['data'][item]['country-eng'], d['data'][item]['eng']['advisory-text']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question. Here's how to do it:

```
import json

with open('traveladvisory.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
#    print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))  # pretty-print data read

for country in d['data']:
    print(country)
    print('  country-eng: {}'.format(d['data'][country]['country-eng']))
    print('  advisory-state: {}'.format(d['data'][country]['advisory-state']))
```

Output:

```
DZ
  country-eng: Algeria
  advisory-state: 1
AL
  country-eng: Albania
  advisory-state: 0
AF
  country-eng: Afghanistan
  advisory-state: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Then the code bellow work for python2 (if you need the python3 version please ask)
You have to use the [load](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) function from the [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) **module**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json                            # import the module we need

with open("traveladvisory.json") as f: # f for file
    d = json.load(f)                   # d is a dictionnary

for key in d['data']:
    print d['data'][key]['country-eng']
    print d['data'][key]['eng']['advisory-text']
```

It is good practice to use the **with** statement when dealing with file objects.
This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

Also, the json is wrong, you have to remove to comma from line 98:

```
{
   "metadata":{
      "generated":{
         "timestamp":1475854624,
         "date":"2016-10-07 11:37:04"
      }
   },
   "data":{
      "AF":{
         "country-id":1000,
         "country-iso":"AF",
         "country-eng":"Afghanistan",
         "country-fra":"Afghanistan",
         "advisory-state":3,
         "date-published":{
            "timestamp":1473866215,
            "date":"2016-09-14 11:16:55",
            "asp":"2016-09-14T11:16:55.000000-04:00"
         },
         "has-advisory-warning":1,
         "has-regional-advisory":0,
         "has-content":1,
         "recent-updates-type":"Editorial change",
         "eng":{
            "name":"Afghanistan",
            "url-slug":"afghanistan",
            "friendly-date":"September 14, 2016 11:16 EDT",
            "advisory-text":"Avoid all travel",
            "recent-updates":"The Health tab was updated - travel health notices (Public Health Agency of Canada)."
         },
         "fra":{
            "name":"Afghanistan",
            "url-slug":"afghanistan",
            "friendly-date":"14 septembre 2016 11:16 HAE",
            "advisory-text":"\u00c9viter tout voyage",
            "recent-updates":"L'onglet Sant\u00e9 a \u00e9t\u00e9 mis \u00e0 jour - conseils de sant\u00e9 aux voyageurs (Agence de la sant\u00e9 publique du Canada)."
         }
      },
      "AL":{
         "country-id":4000,
         "country-iso":"AL",
         "country-eng":"Albania",
         "country-fra":"Albanie",
         "advisory-state":0,
         "date-published":{
            "timestamp":1473350931,
            "date":"2016-09-08 12:08:51",
            "asp":"2016-09-08T12:08:51.8301256-04:00"
         },
         "has-advisory-warning":0,
         "has-regional-advisory":1,
         "has-content":1,
         "recent-updates-type":"Editorial change",
         "eng":{
            "name":"Albania",
            "url-slug":"albania",
            "friendly-date":"September 8, 2016 12:08 EDT",
            "advisory-text":"Exercise normal security precautions (with regional advisories)",
            "recent-updates":"An editorial change was made."
         },
         "fra":{
            "name":"Albanie",
            "url-slug":"albanie",
            "friendly-date":"8 septembre 2016 12:08 HAE",
            "advisory-text":"Prendre des mesures de s\u00e9curit\u00e9 normales (avec avertissements r\u00e9gionaux)",
            "recent-updates":"Un changement mineur a \u00e9t\u00e9 apport\u00e9 au contenu."
         }
      },
      "DZ":{
         "country-id":5000,
         "country-iso":"DZ",
         "country-eng":"Algeria",
         "country-fra":"Alg\u00e9rie",
         "advisory-state":1,
         "date-published":{
            "timestamp":1475593497,
            "date":"2016-10-04 11:04:57",
            "asp":"2016-10-04T11:04:57.7727548-04:00"
         },
         "has-advisory-warning":0,
         "has-regional-advisory":1,
         "has-content":1,
         "recent-updates-type":"Full TAA review",
         "eng":{
            "name":"Algeria",
            "url-slug":"algeria",
            "friendly-date":"October 4, 2016 11:04 EDT",
            "advisory-text":"Exercise a high degree of caution (with regional advisories)",
            "recent-updates":"This travel advice was thoroughly reviewed and updated."
         },
         "fra":{
            "name":"Alg\u00e9rie",
            "url-slug":"algerie",
            "friendly-date":"4 octobre 2016 11:04 HAE",
            "advisory-text":"Faire preuve d\u2019une grande prudence (avec avertissements r\u00e9gionaux)",
            "recent-updates":"Les pr\u00e9sents Conseils aux voyageurs ont \u00e9t\u00e9 mis \u00e0 jour \u00e0 la suite d\u2019un examen minutieux."
         }
      }

   }
}
```